# React pagination add api data which is pagewise

Tags: reactjs

I am using API which has data pagewise and wants to show it on pagination,
below is the code mentioned.
can anyone tell me how to do it?
basically, every page has 6 results and I don't know how to show results using pagination click.
I used Axios to get API.
edit :- api is https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2 and every page have different data.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [perPage] = useState(10);
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0)


  const getData = async() => {
      const res = await axios.get(`https://reqres.in/api/users`)
      const data = res.data.data;
                const slice = data.slice(offset, offset + perPage)
                const postData = slice.map(pd => <div key={pd.id}>
<table>
  <tr>
  <th>{pd.id}</th>
  <th>{pd.email}</th>
  <th>{pd.first_name}</th>
  <th>{pd.last_name}</th>
  <img src={pd.avatar} alt=""/>
  </tr>
</table>
              </div>)
                setData(postData)
                setPageCount(Math.ceil(data.length / perPage))
  }
  const handlePageClick = (e) => {
    const selectedPage = e.selected;
    setOffset(selectedPage + 1)
};

 useEffect(() => {
   getData()
 }, [offset])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data}
       <ReactPaginate
                    previousLabel={"prev"}
                    nextLabel={"next"}
                    breakLabel={"..."}
                    breakClassName={"break-me"}
                    pageCount={pageCount}
                    marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                    onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                    containerClassName={"pagination"}
                    subContainerClassName={"pages pagination"}
                    activeClassName={"active"}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? I suggest you figure out how to show one row of data from the API. Don't worry about pagination until after you can do that.

Comment: i can show data in table form but i need to change data whenever i click on page number in pagination

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. There are several errors in the code as you show it here and some pieces are missing so that I can't run it myself. Then explain what your app does when you run it and what you want it to do differently.

Comment: check post now i have edited code and its working

Comment: So what is your app doing now? And what do you expect it to do differently? Also, `ReactPaginate` does a lot of the work for you. There's no need to do your own `<table>` tag. I suggest you check out [the documentation](https://github.com/AdeleD/react-paginate#readme).

Comment: Solved ..thanks for documentation

Answer (score 0):

Hello In my example per page 6 records display

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);

  // Handle page change
  const handlePageChange = (selectedPage) => {
    setCurrentPage(selectedPage.selected);
  };

  // Generate some sample data
  const data = Array.from(Array(50).keys());

  // Define the number of items per page
  const itemsPerPage = 6;

  // Calculate the index range for the current page
  const startIndex = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
  const endIndex = startIndex + itemsPerPage;

  // Get the current page items
  const currentItems = data.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Render your data using the currentItems */}
      {currentItems.map((item) => (
        <div key={item}>{item}</div>
      ))}

      {/* Render the pagination component */}
      <ReactPaginate
        pageCount={Math.ceil(data.length / itemsPerPage)}
        onPageChange={handlePageChange}
        containerClassName="pagination"
        activeClassName="active"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```